# O que é Borrow Checker?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, garbage-collector, rust

Estava lendo um pouco sobre Rust e me deparei com esse termo, gostaria de saber:

- O que é Borrow Checker?
- Há alguma relação com *reference counting*?
- Qual seria a tradução para esse termo em português?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que é Borrow Checker?

É o analisador de código contido no compilador (não precisaria estar mas em Rust está, faz parte da filosofia da linguagem) que identifica se o tempo de vida de objetos está sendo respeitado.

Quando você tem uma referência para um objeto essa referência tem a propriedade dele, então outra referência só pode ter o objeto por empréstimo, ela não se torna dona do objeto e não pode fazer o que bem entender com ele, por exemplo não pode destruí-lo.

Em alguns casos o analisador de Rust consegue identificar se está tudo ok e coloca anotações de tempo de vida do objeto para você, em outros casos você, programador, deve anotar explicitamente para indicar que há o respeito do empréstimo, o que impedirá certas construções de código que o subverteriam.

Então ele é uma análise estática (tempo de compilação) sobre o tempo de vida do objeto permitindo apenas que seu proprietário o destrua. Ele é que dá segurança de referência para Rust sem criar custo ao executável.

> Há alguma relação com reference counting?

Nenhuma direta. De certa forma tem se considerarmos que é quase uma oposição a ele. Enquanto o empréstimo garante que apenas uma referência tenha a propriedade do objeto e ele é emprestado através de outras referências, a contagem de referência permite que várias referências sejam proprietárias do objeto em conjunto, não necessitando fazer um empréstimo. Ele é um mecanismo de tempo de execução que precisa armazenar e controlar um contador de referências e indicar se o objeto pode ser destruído, por isso tem custo.

> Qual seria a tradução para esse termo em português?

Analisador de empréstimo? Analisador de propriedade poderia encaixar também, mas obviamente não é o mais correto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vou usar o termo em inglês mesmo, em português não soa muito natural

Comment: "Verificador de Empréstimo", literal mesmo.